# Can't generate a CSR request with CA set to true

Tags: openssl

I'm using this config file:

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name

req_extensions = v3_req 

[ req_distinguished_name ]
commonName          = John

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:TRUE
```

And the following command:

```
openssl req -config openssl.conf -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout out.key -out out.csr
```

When attempting to decode the CSR ([decoder](https://certlogik.com)) to make sure everything is expected, I'm only seeing the following properties:

```
Property    Value
Subject CN = John
Key Size    2048 bits
Fingerprint (SHA-1) XX:XX:XX...
Fingerprint (MD5)   XX:XX:XX...
SANS
```

Why am I not seeing the CA set to true?

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I not seeing the CA set to true?

Because you are not looking at the part where it shows this. Look further down at the `CSR Detailed Information`:

```
    Requested Extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
            CA:TRUE
```

If you want to know why these information are not included in the summary and properties section of the output than you have to ask the author of the website/tool you are using.

Apart from that, you don't even need such external tool to look at the CSR details. `openssl req` which you've used to create the CSR is perfectly fine to also look at the CSR details: `openssl req -in out.csr -text`.